# How to fix an error "Prop `className` did not match. Server: "MuiFormLabel-root-75...."?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I use `NextJS` and I tried to user "@material-ui/core" with it. When I've been trying to user `TextFiend` I got the error:

> index.js:2178 Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server:
>   "MuiFormLabel-root-75 MuiInputLabel-root-64
>   MuiInputLabel-formControl-69 MuiInputLabel-animated-72" Client:
>   "MuiFormLabel-root-16 MuiInputLabel-root-5
>   MuiInputLabel-formControl-10 MuiInputLabel-animated-13"

My code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

 export default class Footer extends React.Component {
  static formTypes = ['employer', 'employee']

  formRef = null

  state = {
    formType: Footer.formTypes[0]
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <footer className="footer">
        <div className="footer__content">
          <div className="footer__block">
            <form id="footer__form">
              <TextField type="text" name="name" label="Name"/>

              <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
              <input type="hidden" value={'employer'}/>
            </form>

          </div>

          <div className="footer__block"></div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    )
  }
}
```

What do I have to do for fixing it?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "custom-server-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.6.1",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

I didn't import any part of @material-ui in other files of my codebase. Only the code example.

Comment: did you have a look at this sample : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs ? I think the trick is to use 'createGenerateClassName' method of material-ui to have the same classnames for client and server.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue and was very frustrating... but finally I solved it ...

On my solution I installed reactjs, next and material ui... the problem is releated to how react load the files and styles server and client.

But the important stuff is to do that:

You are using clases but I suggest that change to use hooks like this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

const Footer = (props) => {
    const formTypes = ['employer', 'employee'];
    const formRef = null;

    const [formType, setFormType] = Footer.formTypes[0];

    const myForm = (
        <footer className="footer">
            <div className="footer__content">
            <div className="footer__block">
                <form id="footer__form">
                <TextField type="text" name="name" label="Name"/>

                <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
                <input type="hidden" value={'employer'}/>
                </form>

            </div>

            <div className="footer__block"></div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    );

    return (
        {myForm}
    )
}

export default Footer;
```

but Implementing your code would look like this...

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

export default class Footer extends React.Component {
  static formTypes = ['employer', 'employee']
  formRef = null

  state = {
    formType: Footer.formTypes[0]
  }

  render () {
    const myFormWithClasses = (
             <footer className="footer">
      <div className="footer__content">
        <div className="footer__block">
          <form id="footer__form">
            <TextField type="text" name="name" label="Name"/>

            <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
            <input type="hidden" value={'employer'}/>
          </form>

        </div>

        <div className="footer__block"></div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    )
    return (
     {myFormWithClasses}
    )
 }
}
```

### The key is isolate the elements of the component in a variable to been declared before to be rendered